# Android Studio 3.1.2 0 - no longer see errors in all files (red underlined)

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I feel like I'm going crazy, but since updating to the new version of Android Studio, I can no longer tell which files have errors in them.

Previously, if I made a change in one class, like to a method signature, then all other classes that were calling that method would suddenly be highlighted in red (at that section along the top that shows the path). Now it shows nothing as though my code is good, except when I go to compile, I now get a load of errors in the build tab at the bottom, in a really unhelpful way to navigate through.

Is this something I can switch back to through a setting somewhere? I'm really not sure what to search for, but I've been through almost all of them.

UPDATE :

Following another SO post, I turned on and off PowerSave mode, at the bottom of File menu (in Android Studio). This, temporarily at least, seems to have solved things.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for?

Either that or it may be in preferences.

Comment: They're all still selected, so it's not like any are off.

Comment: Is there an option for syntax highlighting in Preferences. Would imagine it comes under formatting or the likes?

Comment: Not that I can see. See my Update to my question. I *might* have solved it by toggling Power Save mode. I'll keep an eye on it and report back to this question if I think it's solved it

Comment: Nice one, a power saving mode would seems logical to have this effect. Maybe on the upgrade it "bugged" on for some reason